# How can I combine model field and non-model field in ModelForm?

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    model_field = models.CharField()

class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    non_model_field = forms.HiddenInput()
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('model_field', 'non_model_field',)
```

I get an exception:

FieldError

Unknown field(s) (non_model_field) specified for ExampleModel

How can I combine model field and non-model field in ModelForm?

Comment: Actually you don't need to provide `fields`. Maybe this is causing the error.

Comment: but I must provide fields, because my real model-class contains many fields, and I don't want to see in my form some of these fields.

Comment: Tried your approach just now and for me it is working. Though: you know that `HiddenInput` is a widget class, not a form field class. Use something like this instead if you want a hidden input field: `forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)`. Check then again if it works.

Comment: Then I put it into the answer (at least for other people later). Feel free to mark the question as answered. :)

Answer (score 3):

`HiddenInput` is a widget class, not a form field class. Use something like this instead if you want a hidden input field:

`forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)`.